# Fix CORS error using WPGraphQL plugin as a backend and NextJS as frontend

Tags: wordpress, apache, graphql, next.js

I've been struggling with this error after migrating a site from Google Cloud in which I was using Nginx and now I changed the hosting to an Apache server.

The website is in 2 sections front-end (hosted on Vercel NextJS) and the backend which is a WordPress site used as an API with GraphQL (this is the one I migrated) I have used the GraphQL plugin and now the request from the front-end is getting this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at [backend domain] from origin [front end domain] has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have added this to the .htaccess file:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"
```

I'm using Cloudflare in both the backend and the frontend.

Don't know what else to do. I have tried to go back to the previous hosting and it works perfectly so I don't know what's the problem! Please help! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this filter in functions.php file in theme and make sure SSL enabled

```
    add_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', 'cors_headersxxxx', 0, 4 );
    function cors_headersxxxx() {
      header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
      header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE' );
      header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
      header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-Mystore-Cartkey, X-USER-ID' );
      //header( 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Mystore-Cartkey' );
    }


    add_filter('rest_api_init', 'wp_mystore_jwt_add_cors_support');
    function wp_mystore_jwt_add_cors_support() {
      $enable_cors = true;
      if ($enable_cors) {
        $headers = 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization';
        header( sprintf( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: %s', $headers ) );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! Sadly it didn't work. I'm still getting the same error :c

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed! Apparently, I had to flush the permalinks by just saving the permalinks settings:  Settings > Permalinks

I found the solution here: https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql/issues/213

Answer (score 0):

This is not really safety but it works for me

I've put this to .htaccess file

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers '*'
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods '*'
```